Can Ekadashi be auspicious for starting new things despite less auspicious astrological events?
Ekadashi is often chosen as an auspicious day to start new things, but is this also true even if there are astrological events that suggest otherwise?
For example, tomorrow is Mohini Ekadashi. At the same time, Jupiter (Guru Brihaspati) is in combustion with the Sun (Surya dev) — exact before sunrise, but within one degree throughout the day.
Mars (Mangala) is also in exact conjunction with Rahu a day earlier (so still in close proximity on the day of Ekadashi). Alignments with Rahu tend not to be seen as auspicious, and for individuals for whom Mars is significant this alignment may be more discouraging.
This example is just one specific day, which prompted the question, but is anything written about whether actions taken on Ekadashi can remain auspicious despite astrological influences? Are there any examples of things that have gone right (or wrong)?
Also, is the Ekadashi of Shukla Paksha more auspicious for new beginnings than that of Krishna Paksha? Does that have a bearing on whether the influence of Ekadashi can be more significant than that of astrological alignments?
